# Change ggbio tracks labels to horizontal

Tags: r, ggplot2, bioconductor

In base R plot we have [las](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/par.html) option to rotate axis labels.

Is there a way to make labels `time1` and `time2` horizontal, usinig [tracks() function](http://www.tengfei.name/ggbio/docs/man/tracks.html) from [ggbio package](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/ggbio.html)?

```
require(ggplot2)
require(ggbio)

## make a simulated time series data set
df1 <- data.frame(time = 1:100, score = sin((1:100)/20)*10)
p1 <- qplot(data = df1, x = time, y = score, geom = "line")
df2 <- data.frame(time = 30:120, score = sin((30:120)/20)*10, value = rnorm(120-30 + 1))
p2 <- ggplot(data = df2, aes(x = time, y = score)) + 
  geom_line() + geom_point(size = 4, aes(color = value))

#plot
tracks(time1 = p1,time2 = p2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ggbio` function does not seem to include such option. You could do your own ggplot.

```
df1$value = NA
df1$times = "time1"
df2$times = "time2"
df3 = rbind(df1, df2)

ggplot(data = df3, aes(x = time, y = score)) + 
  facet_grid(times~.) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point(size = 4, aes(color = value)) +
  theme(strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 0))
```

You still have the option to save the `track` plot in SVG format and edit the SVG file using [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org).